# What’s a good synonym for when a sports player get mockingly booed by the crowd.?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

Often in sports when a visiting player plays on the court of the home team, he will get booed.

The word I’m looking for has similar meaning to serenade.

“As Lebron James got blocked, the crowd _____ him.”

The word is not booed and compound words and phrases are accepted.

Comment: Why do you say *the word is **not** "booed"?* That's a perfectly good single-word verb for the context. Another is ***heckled***, but that might include Bronx cheers (blowing raspberries), hissing, shouting out specific *verbal* criticisms, etc.

Comment: A common synonym for boos/jeers used by football clubs in media releases etc. is “regrettable crowd behaviour”!

Answer (score 1):

I think jeer sounds good. Heckle, torment or provoke may also suffice although they don’t exactly indicate noise.